# Signal is missing in the sensitivity list and expression truncation

Tags: verilog, signal

For the following module I get several warnings ,can you advice me how to solve them?

*Line 22: Result of 17-bit expression is truncated to fit in 16-bit target.
Line 25: Signal  missing in the sensitivity list is added for synthesis purposes. HDL and post-synthesis simulations may differ as a result.
Line 26: Signal  missing in the sensitivity list is added for synthesis purposes.*

```
module module_cell1( in_85,in_86,in_87,out_13,clk,rst );
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 16;

// Interfaces
input clk;
input rst;

input [DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] in_85,in_86,in_87;
output [DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] out_13;
reg [DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] out_13;

//clk state
reg [DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] clkState;

// Procedural Assignments

always @ ( posedge clk or negedge rst )
begin
if (~rst)
    clkState <= 0;
else
    clkState <= clkState + 1;

//Clk based State
case (clkState)
1: out_13 <= (in_87)?in_86 : in_85;

endcase
end

endmodule
```

Comment: What tool is this? The first warning is legit, but the other two are not. Changing the sensitivity list as they suggest would change the functionality to something other than what you want. If this is some sort of Verilog "lint" tool, you're going to have to get familiar with configuring it to give useful information for your particular situation.

Comment: Synthesis tools are dumb. Always try to follow the documented boilerplate code provided with your synthesis tool. In this case, you combined registers with reset and registers without reset in the same `always` block, which might be confusing the tool. I'd try making a separate always block to control `out_13` and see if that makes the tool happier.

Answer (score 2):

Your always block logic is broken. Exactly as written, the logic you're describing will try to load `out_13` both on clock edge and on reset assertion, because you're not including it in the `else` case.

There's no standard synthesizable equivalent to a flop which loads a dynamic value on positive edge of the clock and when reset is asserted, which is likely why the tool is complaining.

Should look like this instead:

```
always @ ( posedge clk or negedge rst )
begin
if (~rst)
    clkState <= 0;
else begin 
    clkState <= clkState + 1;

    //Clk based State
    case (clkState)
    1: out_13 <= (in_87)?in_86 : in_85;

    endcase
end
end
```

Comment: `out_13` should also be listed in the reset part of the if  statements or be it a separate `always` block. Some tools will complain or give odd results when mixing flops with and without asynchronous resets in the same `always` block.